# XBee node discovery using python API without response

Tags: python, xbee, discovery

I'm trying to get the data of a XBee network (API mode) using python, so I'm using the python-xbee library and the AT 'ND' command to try to discover all XBee units (I'll paste my code just for ND command below):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from xbee import ZigBee 
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600)
xbee = ZigBee(ser)

xbee.at(command='ND')
xbeeAddrs = []
while True:
    try:
        newXBeeR = xbee.wait_read_frame()
        print newXBeeR
        xbeeAddrs.append(newXBeeR['parameter']['source_addr_long'])
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
ser.close()
```

But there is NO response message and the code hangs on waiting for a frame.

For the easiest test I've a XBee Router API board connected to an Arduino Uno with a 7 segments display, and a XBee Coordinator API board connected to the computer using sparkfun uart board.

Other AT commands work properly, however I need to discover all the possible XBee Router units before send commands. If I use the X-CTU software the discover function works perfect...

What could I do?
Thanks a lot,

**UPDATE:**

Solved in comments...

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python` and  `ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600)` in same script ? You create a symlink(for /dev/ttyXXX) ? what is your os ? you define any port(serial) in sketch ?

Comment: you can't connect with only 2 parameters. read this : http://knowledge.digi.com/articles/Knowledge_Base_Article/Parity-settings-on-module where parity,stopbits etc setting

Comment: if you read. i will delete message . because not your correct answer.Or check your scanning program serial parameters !

Comment: Thanks SDilmac, as for `#!/usr/bin/python` and `ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600)` in the same script, that is due to testing reasons while Node Discover isn't working properly. I've already check your link however _in my view_ there is nothing there that could help me :(

Comment: Correct COM port and baud rate?  Is the board in API mode (`ATAP`=1)?

Comment: OMG! Thanks a lot tomlogic! I've already changed ATAP to 1 as you suggested me (I had ATAP=2 after) and now the AT ND command seems to work properly, on the other hand, why ATAP = 1? I ask you because in every site that I've read something about how to configure XBee I've always read ATAP=2 (escape = True), whats the meaning of it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change `xbee = ZigBee(ser)` to `xbee = ZigBee(ser, escaped=true)`

Explanation: By default the API frame are not escaped, i.e the zigbee/xbee object operate in ATAP1 mode. This might not be the case for the actual device (the coordinator). So one fix is to pass escaped=true argument when creating the xbee/zigbee object or configure your device to be in ATP1 mode
`xbee = ZigBee(ser)` should be `xbee = ZigBee(ser, escaped=true)`